# Graph distances as a dist object

Tags: r, graph, distance, igraph

I have a graph with undirected weighted links, and I want to process the graph distance between all of its pairs of nodes. Because it is a large graph, I would like to get the result as a `dist` object (by opposition to a full, symmetric, matrix).

1. Is there a way to do that with igraph? According to the [documentation](http://igraph.org/r/doc/distances.html), it doesn't seem so, but I may be missing something. Obviously, I don't want to get the full symmetric matrix and convert it using `as.dist()`.
2. Is there any alternative R library allowing to get this result?

Thanks.